# C# 5.0 .Net WindowForms application storing user specific settings in config fiel while runtime using Jetbrains Rider

Tags: c#, config, settings

IDE:
JetBrains Rider 2020.3.3
Build #RD-203.7148.23, built on February 17, 2021

Application Info:
Target framework: net5.0-windows7.0
Language version: c# 9.0

https://github.com/githubTh3o2211/simpleBackup/tree/switfUpload/SimpleBackup
on branch swiftUpload

**What i trying to archive ?**
as title mention iam trying to store some user specific data from a settings form to somewehere using .NET configurationManger or equal solution.  So basically iam looking for best pratice information for doing that on a webform application

**What i did before?**
I searched for a long itme but at the end i was landed everytime to this topic:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN

But it seems with my ide i cant use it or i dont know how.

So as you can see, iam more or less looking for a good soul to send me some hints or best pratices

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

to the poor soul who is looking for an alternative, currently iam using a XML file and access it via XElement. After that iam using LINQ to XML to sort and get my values.

If someone who see the need to teach / advise best pratice things, please feel free to do that. Iam open for the right way.

THx